# Defining a function using just compilable functions

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

I need to define a function that takes an input and if and only if its a positive real, outputs the input. If not, the output should be 0. The input could be complex valued or indeterminate.

Heres what I defined;

```
myMax[x_] := 
  Module[{}, 
   If[x === Indeterminate, 0, If[Element[x, Reals], Max[0, x], 0]]];
```

This function is not compilable efficiently in mathematica. Is it possible to define such a function using just [compilable functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions)?

Comment: What do you mean "not compilable efficiently"? Would this work? `myMax = Compile[{{x, _Complex}}, If[Im@x==0, Max[Re@x, 0], 0]]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way, but it should work as expected and is also compilable:

```
If[Re[x] > 0 && Im[x] == 0, x, 0]
```

Note that `Indeterminate` is a Mathematica construct and cannot be used inside a compilable function without reverting back to the main kernel. For example, see the error messages if you do:

```
Compile[{x, y}, x/y][0, 0]
(*Indeterminate*)
```

> *CompiledFunction::cfne: Numerical error encountered; **proceeding with uncompiled evaluation**.*
>
> *Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.*
>
> *Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.*

Therefore, if you expect that `Indeterminate` could happen in your code, it is best to check the values of arguments *before* executing a possibly dangerous operation, for example (giving 0 for problematic numbers as in your case):

```
Compile[{x, y}, If[y == 0, 0, x/y]][0, 0]
(* 0. *)
```